# Marionette - how to run my onshow in view when Collection is shown

Tags: marionette

I have to use marionette, and a collectionview and an itemview. There is no getting around this requirement, so whatever awful hacks have to be done to be able to make things work will have to be done.

Anyway in the annotated marionette documentation we have

```
  addItemView: function(item, ItemView, index){
   ....
    if (view.onShow){
      this.onShowCallbacks.add(view.onShow, view);
    }
```

and

```
 onShowCalled: function(){
    this.onShowCallbacks.run();
  },
```

inside of the collectionview

I have my view

```
   var dynamicView = baseView.extend({
        template: function() {
... this template renders fine no problems
        },
         onShow: function(){

             console.log("I am shown");


        }...
```

in my collection view I have an onshow

```
 onShow: function(){
            console.log("showing collection");

        }
```

I have a route that is being called

```
  var myView = new contentCollectionView({
                        collection: collection,

                        tagName: "div",
                        className: "dashboard"
                    });

                    myView.close();
                    myapp.content.show(myView);
```

Everything renders.

I get the showing collection output to the console, but I do not get the I am shown output, even though the template that it has is rendered and everything shows up in my DOM at the end.

Answer (score 0):

**onShow** and **onRender** fire in different contexts.

In my experience, **onShow** is mostly called when a view is added to a **Region**. Check out the [Marionette Region Wiki](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.region.md).

When a **CollectionView** is *rendering* an **ItemView** it actually calls `render` on the **ItemView** which triggers **onRender** not **onShow**. Check out [these lines in the Marionette CollectionView Source](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/src/marionette.collectionview.js#L318-L321).

If you've been following the logic here, your solution is to define `onRender` instead of `onShow` in your **ItemView**.

Hope that helps!